# How to calculate a score system

Tags: regression, biostatistics

How can i create a scoring system using different variables (like score used in medicine)? I can calculate a regression equation but i'm having trouble converting this equation to a score assigning point to the different variables. Any suggestions or sources i can read about? Thanks